# Where would one find LaTeX flashcards?

Tags: learning, anki

I've always been of the mind that, if I'm to take a language seriously, I need to memorize a certain amount of terms.

With that in mind, I'm planning on creating a flashcard deck with Anki and/or Quizlet...if I can't find an already-done list.

So, where can one find flashcards related to LaTeX?

Comment: Not used it but anki crops up from time to time here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=anki

Comment: Once upon a time I used [this](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=9933). I worked great but *lots* of fine-tuning was needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you look at [the ctan topic search](http://www.ctan.org/topic/card-flash) you can see several.  while checking this, i stumbled across the `ecards` package which may also be useful.  (when the database gets updated again, `ecards` will show, too.)

i make no claims for any of these, other than that they looked like flash-card-y sorts of things when i was doing the topic catalogue.